# No Title - Wordpress facebook share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I have created my website using wordpress 3.4.1 and, I tried sharing my webpage in facebook. I do not get any thumbnail or the basic blog description in the facebook post. Instead I get "No Title". I know this question has been asked a number of times in wordpress forums. But, most of them are leading to dead ends. Can some one help me in this regard.

PS: I tried using the facebook debugger (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) I get the following

Error Parsing URL:  Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.

Comment: This means that Facebook can't connect to your blog. Check access logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like what Niraj said you need to make sure you have the open graph meta tags on your blog. Here is a plugin which will add them http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-open-graph-meta/.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add OpenGraph tags to your page, or even easier, finf a WordPress plugin to do it for you. Run the page through the debugger again and the issues should be fixed.